# Glitch on image change

Tags: jquery

For the most part my images change, but quite often it will do a glitched like change and the image will stay the same.

```
$(window).ready(function () {
  //variable images = array
  var images = [];

  var loop, i = 0;

  //set array images to index
  images[0] = "design/img/NYC.jpg";
  images[1] = "design/img/meandning.jpg";

  $('#imgz').load(function () {
      var image = this;
      loop = setInterval(function () {
          if (i < images.length - 1) {
              i++;
              $(image).attr('src', images[i]);
          } else {
              i = 0;
              $(image).attr('src', images[i]);
          }
      }, 2000);

  })
});
```

Comment: What is `show`? Edit: I'm only asking because I don't see anything else immediately wrong.

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to be removed, but a friend was trying to help me and said this was supposed to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.load` event fires everytime you change the `src` meaning that you are creating a new `setInterval` every time. You can use `.one()` to only bind the event to the first image load...

```js
//variable images = array
  var images = [];

  var loop, i = 0;

  //set array images to index
  images[0] = "http://placehold.it/400x400?text=Slide%201";
  images[1] = "http://placehold.it/400x400?text=Slide%202";

  $('#imgz').one('load',function () {
      var image = this;
      loop = setInterval(function () {
          if (i < images.length - 1) {
              i++;
              $(image).attr('src', images[i]);
          } else {
              i = 0;
              $(image).attr('src', images[i]);
          }

          //show.html(i);
      }, 2000);

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="imgz" src="http://placehold.it/400x400?text=Slide%200">
```

The "glitch" you see is caused by multiple `setInterval` all changing the `src` at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, just learning how to do web development much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Learning to use your browsers development tools will help you to debug issues like this. Add `console.log(i);` within your `setInterval()` code and the console will show you how the number of setIntervals grows exponentially.